# How to redirect video to another video?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, video

How to redirect video to another video ?

For example: I have only 1 video: `http://mywebsite.com/video.mp4`

And when I access one of videos below, the content of above video will be showed. How to do that ? Thank you very much !

```
http://mywebsite.com/1.mp4
http://mywebsite.com/2.mp4
http://mywebsite.com/3.mp4
http://mywebsite.com/4.mp4
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^\d+\.mp4$ video.mp4 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hello, Your code work like a charm. If I want to redirect http://mywebsite.com/abcd-anycharacter-gdc.mp4 to video.mp4, how to do it ? Thanks !

Comment: You can use: `RewriteRule ^(?!video\.).+?\.mp4$ video.mp4 [L,NC]`